# Register a com dll windows container. Please suggest the steps and the docker file

Tags: docker, com

We need to register a com dll(32 Bit) using docker, since we need to use windows container. Please suggest the steps and the docker file.

I tried using regsvr32 in docker file but it did not register and so it is not working.